# How do I get emacs to write to read-only files automatically?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am finding myself editing a lot of files that are read-only.  I usually hit `C-x C-q` to call `toggle-read-only`.  Then I hit `C-x C-s` to save and get,

```
File foo.txt is write-protected; try to save anyway? (y or n)
```

After hitting `y`, the file is saved and the permissions on the file remain read-only.

Is there a way to shorten this process and make it so that simply saving a file with C-x C-s does the whole thing without prompting?  Should I look into inserting `chmod` in `before-save-hook` and `after-save-hook` or is there a better way?

Comment: I was trying to come up with an alternative for you that was more targeted and I've hit upon some strange behavior when trying to advise the primitive `file-writable-p`.  You can follow the other question f you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075862/how-to-advise-primitives-in-emacs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a call to `chmod` in `before-save-hook` would be clean way to accomplish this.  There isn't any setting you can change to avoid the permissions check.

Based on the follow-up question, it sounds like you'd like the files to be changed to writable by you automatically upon opening.  This code does the trick:

```
(defun change-file-permissions-to-writable ()
  "to be run from find-file-hook, change write permissions"
  (when (not (file-writable-p buffer-file-name))
    (chmod buffer-file-name (file-modes-symbolic-to-number "u+w" (nth 8 (file-attributes buffer-file-name))))
    (if (not (file-writable-p buffer-file-name))
        (message "Unable to make file writable."))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'change-file-permissions-to-writable)
```

Note: When I tested it on my Windows machine, the file permissions didn't show up until I tried to save the buffer, but it worked as expected.  I personally feel uneasy about this customization, but it's your Emacs. :)

Comment: What can I do to I automate toggle-read-only? Is there a hook that fires when a file is visited?

Comment: @sigjuice There's a `find-file-hook` you can use.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Trey that universally doing a chmod on write is risky -- read-only files are read-only for a reason, IMHO.  Here's a way to specifically override things on a per-buffer basis.  It's not ideal in that it overrides `file-writable-p` for the life of the buffer (or at least until you toggle `my-override-mode-on-save` back to nil), but it makes you make a conscious decision on a file-by-file basis (sort-of; it's really a buffer-by-buffer basis, which is fairly similar).  Of course since you're looking to automatically toggle the read-only flag when the file is visited, you might not be interested in this distinction.  Still, here it is; enjoy it or ignore it as you will.

```
(make-variable-buffer-local
 (defvar my-override-mode-on-save nil
   "Can be set to automatically ignore read-only mode of a file when saving."))

(defadvice file-writable-p (around my-overide-file-writeable-p act)
  "override file-writable-p if `my-override-mode-on-save' is set."
  (setq ad-return-value (or
                         my-override-mode-on-save
                         ad-do-it)))

(defun my-override-toggle-read-only ()
  "Toggle buffer's read-only status, keeping `my-override-mode-on-save' in sync."
  (interactive)
  (setq my-override-mode-on-save (not my-override-mode-on-save))
  (toggle-read-only))
```

P.S. Thanks to Trey for the `ad-return-value` pointer in the [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075862/how-to-advise-primitives-in-emacs/3076418#3076418).

Answer (score 1):

Since I find it useful to be constantly reminded that I am about to edit a file I do not have permissions to, when I open a file in a buffer I want to force myself to proactively make the buffer writable wit `C-x q`. Opening it with tramp by hand however is quite tedious so I advise `save-buffer` to prompt me for password if it fails to write. I totally recommend you put this snippet in your `.emacs`

```
(defadvice save-buffer (around save-buffer-as-root-around activate)
  "Use sudo to save the current buffer."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (and (buffer-file-name) (not (file-writable-p (buffer-file-name))))
      (let ((buffer-file-name (format "/sudo::%s" buffer-file-name)))
    ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a reason I could no determine the Trey Jackson [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074204/2496970) does not work on my gnu emacs 25.2 under windows: the `file-modes-rights-to-number` called from `file-modes-rights-to-number` fails. 
If someone is stuck with the same problem he could use a less elegant but working solution replace block :

```
(chmod buffer-file-name (file-modes-symbolic-to-number "u+w" (nth 8 (file-attributes buffer-file-name))))
```

with block :

```
(cond ((or (eq system-type 'ms-dos) (eq system-type 'windows-nt))
              (progn
                (shell-command-to-string (concat "attrib -R " (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))
                (message "Setting file and buffer to writeable (%s style)" system-type)
              ))
           ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
              (progn
              (shell-command-to-string (concat "chmod u+w " (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))
              (message "Setting file and buffer to writeable (%s style)" system-type)
             ))
           (t (message "file permission change not handle for OS %s" system-type))               
)
```