# How to advise primitives in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, advising-functions, defadvice

I was trying to answer [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074111/how-do-i-get-emacs-to-write-to-read-only-files-automatically) when I hit upon some very odd behavior.  Here's my little test case:

```
(make-variable-buffer-local
 (defvar my-override-mode-on-save nil
   "Can be set to automatically ignore read-only mode of a file when saving."))

(defadvice file-writable-p (around my-overide-file-writeable-p act)
  "override file-writable-p if `my-override-mode-on-save' is set."
  (or
   my-override-mode-on-save
   ad-do-it))

(defun my-override-toggle-read-only ()
  "Toggle buffer's read-only status, keeping `my-override-mode-on-save' in sync."
  (interactive)
  (setq my-override-mode-on-save (not my-override-mode-on-save))
  (toggle-read-only))

(defun tester-fn ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((xxx (file-writable-p "/tmp/foofoo"))
        (yyy (file-writable-p "/tmp/fooxxfoo")))
    (message (concat "XXX: " (if xxx "yes" "no") "   -   YYY: " (if yyy "yes" "no")))))
```

where:

- `/tmp/foofoo` is a read-only file that I've visited and run `my-override-toggle-read-only` in.
- `/tmp/fooxxfoo` does not exist.
- `/tmp` is writable by the user I'm logged in as.

If I run `tester-fn` in a buffer where `my-override-mode-on-save` is set to `t` then I get an unexpected result: `XXX: no   -   YYY: no`.  If I run `tester-fn` while in some other buffer (e.g. *scratch*) I get the expected response in the minibuffer: `XXX: no   -   YYY: yes`.  Tracing the advice through the debugger shows it to be doing exactly what I think it should be doing, executing the parts I expect it to, skipping the parts I expect it to, returning the value I expect it to.  However, tracing `tester-fn` through the debugger shows very different values being returned (`nil` & `t` if the variable evaluates as nil, `nil` & `nil` if the variable evaluates as non-nil).  The `nil` & `nil` return is really what I find bizarre.

I have no clue what's happening here.  Anyone know why I'm not getting the results I expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks good, except the one missing key.  You need to set the return value appropriately:

```
(defadvice file-writable-p (around my-overide-file-writeable-p act)
  "override file-writable-p if `my-override-mode-on-save' is set."
  (setq ad-return-value
        (or
         my-override-mode-on-save
         ad-do-it)))
```

This is documented in the [advice manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Comment: I've always thought that `ad-return-value` was used to override the return value, not set it (and the manual says as much).  But this was indeed the missing piece -- thanks!

Comment: the difference (for me) is the assumption that the return value will be normal (i.e. the last evaluated expression) and `ad-return-value` would be used to change that.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte Ah, I always interpreted advice as giving you hooks to change behavior, but that (quoting) "After-advice and around-advice can override the return value by setting ad-return-value." But I can see your POV.